# Solving ODES in PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The PDE given as:
$$t^2u_t-\text{yu}_x+\text{xu}_y\text{=0}$$

The characteristic equations are:
$$\frac{\text{dt}}{\text{dt}}=t^2$$
$$\frac{\text{dx}}{\text{dt}}\text{=-y}$$
$$\frac{\text{dy}}{\text{dt}}\text{=x}$$

My solution to x and y respectively is:

$$x=y\tau + \xi _0$$
$$y=x\tau$$

However, the solutions given by my book are:

$$x=\xi_0Cos\tau-\nu_0Sin\tau$$
$$y=\xi_0Sin\tau+\nu_0Cos\tau$$
$$t=-1/\tau$$

How did the book arrived at their own solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the variable $t$ in two different way. you are also forgetting that a solution of $\frac{dx}{d\tau} = -y$ is not $x = -\tau y$ because $y$ is also a function of $\tau.$

i will use a new variable $s$ instead. so we have $$\frac{dt}{ds} = t^2, \frac{dx}{ds} = -y, \frac{dy}{ds} = x \to \frac{d^2x}{ds^2} + x = 0  $$ so that $$x = a\cos(s-b), y = -\frac{dx}{ds} = a\sin(s-b), t = \frac{1}{c-s}.$$

Comment: How does $$x=acos(s-b)$$? I haven't revisited the techniques to solving ODEs for more than a year so I would have forgotten a lot of stuffs. Is there a formula or theorem? Is it related to the method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: Also I think there should be a *negative sign infront of c in your solution for t.

Comment: @user,  the differential equation $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + x = 0$ represents the simple harmonic motion. the solutions is sinusoid wave. if you forget that you can still try $x = e^{\lambda t}$ and get the characteristic equation $\lambda^2 + 1 = 0.$ that has roots $\lambda = \pm i.$  $c$ is an arbitrary constant, so it does not matter if you have $\pm.$

Comment: Seems like I need to revisit topics on "method of undetermined coefficients".

Comment: method of undetermined coefficients finds a particular solution to a differential equation. for example if you have $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + x = \cos 2t.$  what i was talking about earlier is finding the hgs  solutions.

Comment: What is non-abbreviated form for hgs in this context? "Homogenous"?

Comment: @user, i did not want to spell the whole homogeneous. that is the right hand side of the differential equation, sometimes interpreted as force,  is zero.

Comment: I know where to review my understanding now. Thank for pointing me in the right direction. It is a second-order homogenous PDE.

Comment: @user, you are welcome. have fun reading/doing differential equation.